# How to view contraints of a cloumn in postgresSql?

Tags: postgresql, constraint, heroku

I applied a constraint but forgot its name. Now I want to drop it using `ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME] DROP CONSTRAINT [CONSTRAINTNAME]` . If there is a way to drop all constraint from a column that should work too. 
I cannot use psql command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL exposes the constraints as well as other schema details through [`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-table-constraints.html), so to find all the constraints for the table, query `table_constraints`, for example:

```
SELECT constraint_name FROM information_schema.table_constraints
    WHERE table_name='my_table' AND constraint_type='UNIQUE';
```

To find which columns are involved into the constraints, check [`constraint_column_usage`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-constraint-column-usage.html).

Comment: This did listed all constraints but is there any solution if I want to know constraints applied on a particular column only?

Comment: @NoName yes, it's [`constraint_column_usage`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-constraint-column-usage.html).